# Matplotlib plot - simplification

Tags: python, matplotlib

I tried several ways to clean up this code a bit, but failed each time. I'm looking to simply clean this up.

```
fig1 = plt.figure()
ax = fig1.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8])
ax.scatter(highForecastTemp, highActTemp)
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.set_xlim(min(x),max(x))
ax.set_ylim(min(x),max(x))
ax.set_title('Forecast vs Actual - High Temperature')
ax.set_xlabel('Forecasted')
ax.set_ylabel('Actual')
plt.show()

fig2 = plt.figure()
ax = fig2.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8])
ax.scatter(lowForecastTemp, lowActTemp)
ax.plot(a, b)
ax.set_xlim(min(a),max(a))
ax.set_ylim(min(a),max(a))
ax.set_title('Forecast vs Actual - Low Temperature')
ax.set_xlabel('Forecasted')
ax.set_ylabel('Actual')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Not clear what do you mean by 'clean up'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing a function can help to clean up:

```
def plot_forecast(x, y, forecast_temp, act_temp, high_low)
    fig1 = plt.figure()
    ax = fig1.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8])
    ax.scatter(forecast_temp, act_temp)
    ax.plot(x, y)
    ax.set_xlim(min(x),max(x))
    ax.set_ylim(min(x),max(x))
    ax.set_title('Forecast vs Actual - {} Temperature'.format(high_low))
    ax.set_xlabel('Forecasted')
    ax.set_ylabel('Actual')
    plt.show()

plot_forecast(x, y, highForecastTemp, highActTemp, 'High')
plot_forecast(a, b, lowForecastTemp, lowActTemp, 'Low')
```

Now, you can call `plot_forecast` with the values that actually change between the plots. You don't need to duplicate all your plotting logic.